# How to make sure that Google Play delivers the most recent version?

Tags: android, google-play

A few weeks ago, I've changed an App from internal testing to open testing on Google play. Lets call it build 20. Since then a few updates have been published and now the current version is build 27.

Yesterday I've noticed that if you download the app from Google Play, you'll get build 20 installed. The question now is: How can you ensure that Google Play delivers the most recent version when installing the app? Is there a way to force it?

A workaround to get the latest version is to visit the "My apps and games" section at the play store app, where the just freshly installed app shows up under available updates. Pushing the "update" button installs the app's latest version (build 27). However, it would be nice if the Play store would deliver the most recent version during initial installation. Do you have any ideas how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

When you change from the Internal or Open testing stage to the Production stage, make sure that **Staged roll-out** is 100%

Of course, it takes several hours to distribute all new users or existing users

[image]